# Why does emacs align weird after array in a hash?

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation

If I get emacs 24.1.1 to indent the following

```
$config = {
    b  => [
           "123",
           ],
    c => "123",
    };
```

then it will turn it into

```
$config = {
    b  => [
           "123",
           ],
        c => "123",
    };
```

**Question**

Why does it not indent so `b` and `c` is aligned?

**Update**

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption                                   
File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar                                         
Transient-Mark                                                                                           

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Perl mode defined in `perl-mode.el':
Major mode for editing Perl code.
```

Comment: This struck me as similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24494901/113848), though the root cause of this behaviour is probably different.

Comment: Looks like an Emacs bug. Use M-x report-emacs-bug :)

Comment: Feel free to give us some more info such as which major mode is in use.

Comment: @Stefan now updated OP with version 24.1.1

Comment: Thanks.  How 'bout the major mode?

Comment: @Stefan I have never heard about major mode. is what I have just added what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The main problem is that it was not even clear which language you were writing in.  Not being sufficiently familiar with all languages, to me it looked like it could be PHP, or Perl, or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the indentation algorithm did not understand this case.

I have just installed a patch to perl-mode.el (in Emacs's trunk, i.e. won't be in the upcoming Emacs-24.4 but only in Emacs-24.5) which seems to fix it.  You can try the new code at http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/progmodes/perl-mode.el.

Comment: If I add that file to one of the search paths, then perl mode is disabled. Do I need to do something besides adding the `perl-mode.el`?

Comment: No, that should be it.  What happens if you `M-x load-file RET ..the/new/perl-mode.el RET`?

Comment: That worked =) How do I add it to my `.emacs` so it is loaded correct?

Comment: Hmm.. don't know why just putting the file in the search path disables the mode while loading it explicitly works fine.  The simplest is probably to `(load "../the/new/perkl-mode.el")`.  Otherwise, try to ask for debugging help on gnu.emacs.help (which tends to work better for that than stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `cperl-mode` instead of `perl-mode`: put

```
(fset 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
```

in your `.emacs`.

Comment: This works, but also changes how indentation is done on `b`. Before `b` were at column 5 and after it is aligned with the `{`. Can that be avoided?